# How do I make a Restangular POST?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have the following in my Angular Model:

```
return Restangular.all('user/session/authenticate').post({user_id: user_id, password: password});
```

Which I call in my controller:

```
User.authenticate($scope.user.userId, $scope.user.username)
    .then(function (authToken) {
      //do stuff
    };
```

But, it never makes a request. The headers are created, the data is there, and there is no error. I know it's probably me, but for the life of me, I can't figure out what. Also, I can successfully make GET requests to the same service.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem wasn't me...sort of. I had the correct Restangular syntax, but a lack of understanding of how my browser works. The browser wanted me to confirm a security exception. No error was given, until I put the url directly into the url bar in FireFox.

Once I confirmed the security exception, the requests began to work.